# SQL Join Query Confusion - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have three tables in MySQL.

- `customers` which has columns `{id, name, and email}`
- `products` which has columns `{id and name}`
- `purchased` which contains `{id, customer}`
- `product` where customer and *product* are *indexes* of `customers.id` and `products.id` respectively.

I am a little confused on how to get the customer's name and all products he has purchased. Here is what I have and it is basically returning all possible combinations of products and customers instead of the specific customers info:

```
SELECT 
    customers.email, 
    products.name 
FROM 
    customers, products, purchased
INNER JOIN 
    customers cu
ON 
    cu.id = purchased.customer
INNER JOIN 
    products pr
ON 
    pr.id = purchased.product
WHERE 
    purchased.customer = 1
```

I expect this to return all products purchased by a customer with ID of 1 but it is not.  Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the explicit and implicit join and hence creating the issue.
You may have the query as below. In addition you have used alias for the joining tables and need to use them in the select as well.

```
SELECT cu.email, pr.name FROM purchased
    INNER JOIN customers cu
    ON cu.id = purchased.customer
    INNER JOIN products pr
    ON pr.id = purchased.product
WHERE pr.customer = 1
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work perfectly.  Seems like my main problem was the FROM clause pulling info from all the tables instead of just the purchased table.   Also I had a type in the question in the WHERE clause.  That should be purchased.customer but your explanation was perfect